# How to make a 1 by 3 matrix into a 4 by 6 matrix with a certain property

Tags: matrices

I have matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$. Is there a matrix that this can be multiplied by (or any other operations) to produce a matrix like this: $\begin{bmatrix}1&-4&3&0&0&0\\0&1&-4&3&0&0\\0&0&1&-4&3&0\\0&0&0&1&-4&3\\\end{bmatrix}$? I was thinking it might be something similar to an identity matrix but I was not sure how to find it. Thanks!

Comment: No for multiplication, because the matrix size won't match.

Comment: Looks like convolution with a $4\times4$ identity matrix to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resultant matrix is equal to the result of the following convolution:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-4&3\end{bmatrix}*
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix} = A*I_4,$$
with the treatment that convolution of two matrices may enlarge matrix size, instead of wrapping or trimming the resultant matrix.